# terraform locked state file s3 solution

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to fix the well known issue with having multiple pipelines and colleagues are running terraform plan and getting the following error:

```
│ Error: Error acquiring the state lock
```

I would like to know if there is any source of the possible ways to get rid of this issue so ci/cd and engineers can run plan without needing to wait for a long time until they are able to work.

Even hashicorp is saying to be careful with force unlock there are risks for multiple writes:

> Be very careful with this command. If you unlock the state when
> someone else is holding the lock it could cause multiple writers.
> Force unlock should only be used to unlock your own lock in the
> situation where automatic unlocking failed.

Is there a way that we can write the file to the disk before performing the plan ?

Comment: You could queue the pipeline executions such that each pipeline execution is gated by the previous execution. Alternatively, you could also implement a wait on acquiring the state lock within the pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

The locking is there to protect you. You may run a plan *(or [apply](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/apply#lock-false))* with [`--lock=false`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/plan#lock-false):

```
terraform plan --lock=false
```

But **I wouldn't encourage that** as you may lose the benefits of state locking, it's there to protect you from conflicting modifications made to your infrastructure.

You would like to run a `terraform plan` against the most recent state which is usually written by the very last `apply` operation you run on your main/master branch.

If the plan takes too long to apply or to run while your engineers are working on different sub-parts of the infrastructure, you would consider a possible refactoring where you break your infrastructure to multiple folders where you run a separate terraform plan/apply for each of them [(src)](https://cloud.google.com/docs/terraform/best-practices-for-terraform#minimize-resources), of course this may come with cost of refactoring and moving resources from a state to another.

One other approach is to disable the state refresh on PR pipelines by setting a [`--refresh=false`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/plan#refresh-false) which is as well not making you take the full advantages of Terraform's state management with diffs and state locking.

---

And of course, as a last resort for few exceptions where you have a locked state, you may consider running a manual [`terraform force-unlock [options] LOCK_ID`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/force-unlock) in few exceptions (for example when a plan gets cancelled, or the runner drops connection so it doesn't release the state).

Resources:

- https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/state/locking
- https://cloud.google.com/docs/terraform/best-practices-for-terraform
- https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/28130#issuecomment-801422713

Comment: Thanks a lot for the recommendations. I believe that the the refresh false option is the most suitable as we do not use plan in pipelines only in certain environments.
Also I found a nice description of the plan command that could explain why this option is kind of safe to use:
`
The terraform plan command lets you to preview the actions Terraform would take to modify your infrastructure, or save a speculative plan which you can apply later. 

`The function of terraform plan is speculative: you cannot apply it unless you save its contents and pass them to a terraform apply command.`

Comment: Nice! Hope that helped you